# Suggestions how to simplify this if statement

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a code which is validating if all form fields are populated with data, but my form inputs are displayed dynamically based on `this.id_company` condition. As you can see if `this.is_company` equals `TRUE` then validation should also check if user has inserted `this.taxNumber` and `this.copmany`

```
isComplete: function () {
    if (this.is_company) {
        return this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email && this.password && this.address && this.postNumber
            && this.city && this.id_country && this.iAggre && this.taxNumber && this.company
    }
    return this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email && this.password && this.address && this.postNumber
        && this.city && this.id_country && this.iAggre;
}
```

I'm searching the best way to simplify my Javascript code. Can you guy please provide examples. Thank you

Comment: "best" .........

Comment: How about something like https://pastebin.com/mgVZvJzn

Comment: @JonasW. that's why Quotations :D i think we can talk this for days :D

Comment: You should avoid asking broad, opinion based questions

Comment: @Scott then how should we know or talk about this kind of questions? How would you tackle this kind of problems? I think this is valid question, so we can see different methods of implementation, discus our problems, etc....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To easy, just use an or:

```
return (
   this.firstName && 
   this.lastName && 
   this.email && 
   this.password && 
   this.address && 
   this.postNumber && 
   this.city && 
   this.id_country && 
   this.iAggre && 
   (!this._isCompany || this.taxNumber && this.company)
);
```

To be read as *and is not a company or has a taxNumber and a company property*.

Answer (score 4):

A nicer, easy to read version would be:

```
isComplete: function () {
    var baseCondition = this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email 
        && this.password && this.address && this.postNumber
        && this.city && this.id_country && this.iAggre

    var companyCondition = baseCondition && this.taxNumber && this.company;

    return this.is_company ? companyCondition : baseCondition;
}
```

Comment: No need to duplicate those conditions, they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You could group your fields in an array, and conditionally push the `company` and `taxNumber` fields:

```
var validate = function(isCompany) {
  var validateFields = [
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.address,
    this.postNumber,
    this.city,
    this.id_country,
    this.iAggre
  ];

  if (isCompany) {
    validateFields.push(this.company, this.taxNumber);
  }

  return validateFields.find(f => !f) === undefined;
}

var isComplete = function() {
  return validate(this.is_company);
}
```

Comment: `this.taxNumber && this.company` predicates should only be checked if `this.is_company`. But other than that, finally something fresh :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to reduce each function down to its simplest form. @jonas-w was going in the right direction by computing values.  The method name documents what the outcome means, and makes the conditional easier to understand.

You can always make `isCompanyComplete()` and `isPersonComplete()` private methods if you don't want to expose them.

Spreading the logical operators (`&&`) over separate lines makes the statement much more readable.

Splitting the ternary statement across separate lines also makes it clear which parts apply to logically true or false.

Avoid inverting logic in conditions (`!this.is_company`).

```js
class Form {

  isPersonComplete() {
    return !!(
      this.firstName 
      && this.lastName 
      && this.email 
      && this.password 
      && this.address 
      && this.postNumber
      && this.city 
      && this.id_country 
      && this.iAgree 
    );
  }

  isCompanyComplete() {
    return !!(
      this.isPersonComplete()
      && !!this.taxNumber 
      && !!this.company
    );
  }

  isComplete() {
    return this.is_company 
      ? this.isCompanyComplete() 
      : this.isPersonComplete();
  }
  
}

const form = new Form()
console.log(
  'Person: ' + form.isPersonComplete(), 
  'Company: ' + form.isCompanyComplete(), 
  'Completed: ' + form.isComplete()
  );


form.firstName = 'John';
form.lastName = 'Smith';
form.email = 'john@smith.co';
form.password = 'somesecret';
form.address = '123 main street, anywhere';
form.postNumber = '12345';
form.city = 'Metropolis';
form.id_country = 1;
form.iAgree = true;
console.log(
  'Person: ' + form.isPersonComplete(), 
  'Company: ' + form.isCompanyComplete(), 
  'Completed: ' + form.isComplete()
  );

form.is_company = true;
form.taxNumber = 12345;
form.company = 'John Smith & Co';
console.log(
  'Person: ' + form.isPersonComplete(), 
  'Company: ' + form.isCompanyComplete(), 
  'Completed: ' + form.isComplete()
  );
```

Comment: I think you messed up some things a bit, but you are generally right, nice approach :)

Comment: Care to offer which bits are messed up?

Answer (score 1):

That this question is "primarily opinion-based", etc is already established, so what the hell, here's another suggestion:

```js
function form() {
  this.vld = {
    fields: ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password", "address", "postNumber", "city", "id_country", "iAggre"],
    check: arr => !arr.some(el => !this[el]),
    isComplete: () => this.vld.check(this.vld.fields) && (!this.is_company || this.vld.check(["taxNumber", "company"]))
  }
}

var stuff = new form();

stuff.firstName = "Alice";
stuff.lastName = "Bob";
stuff.email = "alice@bob.com";
stuff.password = "12abc123";
stuff.address = "123 Main St";
stuff.postNumber = "12345";
stuff.city = "Springfield";
stuff.id_country = 1;
console.log(false, stuff.vld.isComplete());

stuff.iAggre = true;
console.log(true, stuff.vld.isComplete());

stuff.is_company = true;
stuff.taxNumber = "123456789";
console.log(false, stuff.vld.isComplete());

stuff.company = "Moe's";
console.log(true, stuff.vld.isComplete());
```

This method can potentially be optimized by grabbing the names of the input fields from the form itself, which would avoid restating all fields explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Does this work for you?

```
isComplete: function () { 
    let result = this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email && this.password && this.address && this.postNumber && this.city && this.id_country && this.iAggre;
    if (this.is_company) result += this.taxNumber && this.company;
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: `+=`? What types are those values?

Comment: This is rather *or*. May use `*=` to provide the *and* :)

Comment: Must admit, I assumed the values were strings.